# grails System.currentTimeMillis() differ from System-Date

Tags: date, grails, system

I am running centOs with Grails on Tomcat
and when i type `date` in ssh remote shell

it prints

`Mo 2. Jun 18:18:57 CEST 2014`

in the App I tried the following line of code

```
answer.insertDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

which returns the date two hours before so

`16:18:57`

so anybody can explain how I can get the correct system time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEST is 2 hours ahead of UTC.

I believe when you run from shell it uses your system timezone (CEST) but when you run the app (which is programmed to use UTC by default) is 2 hours behind.

Set default timeZone (in `BootStrap.groovy`) to CEST as below if you want CEST timeZone to be used in the app

```
TimeZone.setDefault( TimeZone.getTimeZone( 'Europe/Brussels' ) )
```

Also note, above changes the timeZone for the app altogether (you would see logs with CEST timestamp as well), so choose this setting wisely. If the app expects UTC to be the default timeZone then you can stick to the app and do not alter the default timeZone. :)

Comment: thank you that works perfect, but now i see the real problem, that is when the date is stored in mongodb it is again in utc

Comment: but hteoreticaly thats perfect

Answer (score 1):

I suppose we'd first have to define "system time." The date command returns a locale date adjusted to your time zone and formatted for your language. [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) returns epoch or UTC time without adjusting for time zones, etc.